# Remove Rust from yocto build

Tags: linux, embedded-linux, yocto

I'm trying to remove a series of packages from my yocto build but what I've tried hasn't worked so far. This is what I have:

```
PACKAGE_EXCLUDE += "\
    avahi \
    apt \
    apt-native \
    cmake \
    cmake-native \
    cracklib \
    crda \
    cryptodev-linux \
    dpkg \
    dpkg-native \
    elfutils \
    elfutils-native \
    fftw \
    gawk \
    gcc-runtime \
    gnupg \
    hdparm \
    icu \
    kbd \
    libassuan \
    libatomic-ops \
    libavahi-client \
    libavahi-common \
    libavahi-core \
    libcap-ng \
    libdaemon \
    libgcc \
    libgcc-initial \
    libgcrypt \
    libgpg-error \
    libical \
    libidn2 \
    libksba \
    libmnl \
    libogg \
    libtirpc \
    libtool \
    libtool-cross \
    libubootenv \
    libunistring \
    libxcrypt \
    linux-libc-headers \
    lz4 \
    lzo \
    npth \
    pinentry \
    pulseaudio \
    qemuwrapper-cross \
    resize-helper \
    rust \
    rust-llvm \
    rust-llvm-native \
    rust-native \
    systemd \
    systemd-compat-units \
    systemd-conf \
    systemd-mount-partitions \
    tar \
    vala \
    xxhash \
    zstd \
"
```

The main one I want to remove is Rust, but I still see it building in the log.

I have also tried using `IMAGE_INSTALL:remove` (in fact, I have both at the same time at the moment in my `local.conf` file), but it doesn't seem to work either.

What am I doing wrong here? Is removing Rust even possible?

Thank you.

Edit: Some other packages I'm trying to remove are also appearing in the build log, like `dpkg-native` or `cmake`.

Comment: I have zero knowledge about yocto, but "rustup" and "cargo" are names to look out for when you want to "remove Rust".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have been investigating and I have found that the parameter I wanted to use is `SKIP_RECIPE[rust-native]` in the `local.conf` file. However, rust is a dependency of python3-cryptography and it's not possible to just remove it.